# ajax function not fetching url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have:

```
function makeAjaxRequest() {
var url = '/queryjob/dbname/ip';
$.ajax(url,
{
    success: alert(response)
});
}
```

When I do a normal browser request on this url I get a response of 43(just a test response right now)

When I click the button I have to run this function, nothing happens. I don't see a get request in the log at all.  Do I have some stupid syntax error or something? I am pretty new to js and ajax.  I have another function that works where I get a url and act on the html response code, but this one is killing me so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not calling [**$.ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) correctly. Assuming you wanted to make a GET request, this is the correct syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

You could also use [**$.get**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to accomplish the same thing:

```
$.get(url, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: This did it exactly. I was working from an example that was passing get, and then some data, and I removed them, since I don't have either in my other working example. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/queryjob/dbname/ip",
   success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

Yes, it was a syntax error ;)